# Git Flow Finish Feature Error - no reference found for shorthand 'merge_head'

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitkraken

I am fairly new to Git so I apologize if my terminology is wrong in some areas.  I have a Git repository with many commits directly to master and many branches.  All branches are finished, merged into master, and deleted.  So now I am at a clean slate so to speak.  Since I am at a clean slate, I now want to start using Git Flow.  So I initialized Git Flow in GitKraken, start a new feature, make a simple readme change, commit it, then go to finish the feature.  When I click finish feature I get this error message...

`no reference found for shorthand 'merge_head'`

I have another repository that was setup with Git Flow at the very beginning and it works as expected.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all

*****
This small block was done by another programmer AFTER my original question was posted.
He managed to finish 2 features.  It looks like #54 was done wrong as that feature was
merged into master instead of develop.  But the next one, #55, appears correct.  Would
you agree that it looks like Git Flow is setup properly now?  He said to get past the
original error I posted he had to create the feature, THEN PUSH AND PULL, then finish
feature.  Was that "push and pull" before finishing what we were missing?
*****

*   6232be3 (origin/master) Merge pull request #55 from demoCompany/develop
|\
| *   08cdaf5 (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) Merge branch 'feature/update-readme' into develop
| |\
| | * ec3b33e updated readme again
| |/
* |   05b5957 Merge pull request #54 from demoCompany/develop
|\ \
| |/
| * 780d426 updated readme
|/

*****
What you see below is how the repos looked at the time I posted this question.
Git Flow was not used below.  We initialized Git Flow at this point in time in
GitKraken but when we try to finish a feature we get that merge_head error.
*****

*   46a04ca (master) Merge pull request #53 from demoCompany/Modify-Grid
|\
| * 9a54a94 Save grid column layout
| * 51ec957 Streamline grid loading and add Export
| *   4cd19ec Merge branch 'master' into Modify-Grid
| |\
| * | d9b4ac3 Change CRLF to LF
| * | dd8524f Added export grid drop-down menu
| * | 5abccd7 Require GridController
| * | cb7fa14 Fix Component Name
* | |   18764b6 Merge pull request #52 from demoCompany/fun-with-charts
:...skipping...
*   6232be3 (origin/master) Merge pull request #55 from demoCompany/develop
|\
| *   08cdaf5 (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) Merge branch 'feature/update-readme' into develop
| |\
| | * ec3b33e updated readme again
| |/
* |   05b5957 Merge pull request #54 from demoCompany/develop
|\ \
| |/
| * 780d426 updated readme
|/
*   46a04ca (master) Merge pull request #53 from demoCompany/Modify-Grid
|\
| * 9a54a94 Save grid column layout
| * 51ec957 Streamline grid loading and add Export
| *   4cd19ec Merge branch 'master' into Modify-Grid
| |\
| * | d9b4ac3 Change CRLF to LF
| * | dd8524f Added export grid drop-down menu
| * | 5abccd7 Require GridController
| * | cb7fa14 Fix Component Name
* | |   18764b6 Merge pull request #52 from demoCompany/fun-with-charts
|\ \ \
| * | | e32546a Simple interactive charts with dynamic data load
* | | |   b14d3db Merge pull request #51 from demoCompany/Tree-Filter
|\ \ \ \
| * | | | 7ff5d9a Updated Filters
* | | | |   26ffd2e Merge pull request #50 from demoCompany/Tree-Filter
|\ \ \ \ \
| |/ / / /
| | / / /
| |/ / /
|/| | |
| * | | 6d63da6 Add View Model
| * | | 2c0110c Updated Filter
| * | | fff1691 Added Filters
* | | |   f76d7c5 Merge pull request #48 from demoCompany/make-system-tree-awesome
|\ \ \ \
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
| * | | f7b7fb1 More gooder better
| * | | e766f98 Added more tabs to the system tree
|/ / /
* | |   2dbffbd Merge pull request #44 from demoCompany/check-in-eslint-config
|\ \ \
| * | | 878fd2b Checking in eslint config
|/ / /
* | |   dbf91c0 Merge pull request #43 from demoCompany/enhance-system-tree
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| |
| * | a71eb80 Grid now populates with data
|/ /
* |   e68ee8c Merge pull request #39 from demoCompany/create-kitchen-sink-tree
|\ \
| * | 67df38b Added kitchen sink tree panel
| * | e45e624 More simple updates
| * |   4100b5c Merge branch 'master' into create-kitchen-sink-tree
| |\ \
| | |/
| * | 5bc3fae .wakatime
| * | 0fb7ef9 README updated??
| * |   c67d24c Merge branch 'master' into create-kitchen-sink-tree
| |\ \
| * | | 376bd18 First draft of the system baseline tree
* | | |   6f59b6e Merge pull request #37 from demoCompany/Tree-Branch
|\ \ \ \
| * | | | b7bade7 Created Work Order Tree
| | |/ /
| |/| |
* | | | b488b16 Exlude SDK from indexing
:...skipping...
*   6232be3 (origin/master) Merge pull request #55 from demoCompany/develop
|\
| *   08cdaf5 (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) Merge branch 'feature/update-readme' into develop
| |\
| | * ec3b33e updated readme again
| |/
* |   05b5957 Merge pull request #54 from demoCompany/develop
|\ \
| |/
| * 780d426 updated readme
|/
*   46a04ca (master) Merge pull request #53 from demoCompany/Modify-Grid
|\
| * 9a54a94 Save grid column layout
| * 51ec957 Streamline grid loading and add Export
| *   4cd19ec Merge branch 'master' into Modify-Grid
| |\
| * | d9b4ac3 Change CRLF to LF
| * | dd8524f Added export grid drop-down menu
| * | 5abccd7 Require GridController
| * | cb7fa14 Fix Component Name
* | |   18764b6 Merge pull request #52 from demoCompany/fun-with-charts
|\ \ \
| * | | e32546a Simple interactive charts with dynamic data load
* | | |   b14d3db Merge pull request #51 from demoCompany/Tree-Filter
|\ \ \ \
| * | | | 7ff5d9a Updated Filters
* | | | |   26ffd2e Merge pull request #50 from demoCompany/Tree-Filter
|\ \ \ \ \
| |/ / / /
| | / / /
| |/ / /
|/| | |
| * | | 6d63da6 Add View Model
| * | | 2c0110c Updated Filter
| * | | fff1691 Added Filters
* | | |   f76d7c5 Merge pull request #48 from demoCompany/make-system-tree-awesome
|\ \ \ \
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
| * | | f7b7fb1 More gooder better
| * | | e766f98 Added more tabs to the system tree
|/ / /
* | |   2dbffbd Merge pull request #44 from demoCompany/check-in-eslint-config
|\ \ \
| * | | 878fd2b Checking in eslint config
|/ / /
* | |   dbf91c0 Merge pull request #43 from demoCompany/enhance-system-tree
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| |
| * | a71eb80 Grid now populates with data
|/ /
* |   e68ee8c Merge pull request #39 from demoCompany/create-kitchen-sink-tree
|\ \
| * | 67df38b Added kitchen sink tree panel
| * | e45e624 More simple updates
| * |   4100b5c Merge branch 'master' into create-kitchen-sink-tree
| |\ \
| | |/
| * | 5bc3fae .wakatime
| * | 0fb7ef9 README updated??
| * |   c67d24c Merge branch 'master' into create-kitchen-sink-tree
| |\ \
| * | | 376bd18 First draft of the system baseline tree
* | | |   6f59b6e Merge pull request #37 from demoCompany/Tree-Branch
|\ \ \ \
| * | | | b7bade7 Created Work Order Tree
| | |/ /
| |/| |
* | | | b488b16 Exlude SDK from indexing
* | | | 02a3f77 Updated .gitignore
* | | |   82e1bd6 Merge pull request #35 from demoCompany/mycmproapp-themes
|\ \ \ \
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
| * | | 916c1c5 removed steelgrey stub
| * | | e847962 changed build to steelgrey
| * | | 176b1de Testing Steel Grey switch
| * | | 8ef812e adding steelgray theme
| * | | 3c122f8 Created three themes
| |/ /
* | |   fe7abf2 Merge pull request #33 from demoCompany/Create-Grid
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| |
| * | 4676919 Add .history
:...skipping...
*   6232be3 (origin/master) Merge pull request #55 from demoCompany/develop
|\
| *   08cdaf5 (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) Merge branch 'feature/update-readme' into develop
| |\
| | * ec3b33e updated readme again
| |/
* |   05b5957 Merge pull request #54 from demoCompany/develop
|\ \
| |/
| * 780d426 updated readme
|/
*   46a04ca (master) Merge pull request #53 from demoCompany/Modify-Grid
|\
| * 9a54a94 Save grid column layout
| * 51ec957 Streamline grid loading and add Export
| *   4cd19ec Merge branch 'master' into Modify-Grid
| |\
| * | d9b4ac3 Change CRLF to LF
| * | dd8524f Added export grid drop-down menu
| * | 5abccd7 Require GridController
| * | cb7fa14 Fix Component Name
* | |   18764b6 Merge pull request #52 from demoCompany/fun-with-charts
|\ \ \
| * | | e32546a Simple interactive charts with dynamic data load
* | | |   b14d3db Merge pull request #51 from demoCompany/Tree-Filter
|\ \ \ \
| * | | | 7ff5d9a Updated Filters
* | | | |   26ffd2e Merge pull request #50 from demoCompany/Tree-Filter
|\ \ \ \ \
| |/ / / /
| | / / /
| |/ / /
|/| | |
| * | | 6d63da6 Add View Model
| * | | 2c0110c Updated Filter
| * | | fff1691 Added Filters
* | | |   f76d7c5 Merge pull request #48 from demoCompany/make-system-tree-awesome
|\ \ \ \
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
| * | | f7b7fb1 More gooder better
| * | | e766f98 Added more tabs to the system tree
|/ / /
* | |   2dbffbd Merge pull request #44 from demoCompany/check-in-eslint-config
|\ \ \
| * | | 878fd2b Checking in eslint config
|/ / /
* | |   dbf91c0 Merge pull request #43 from demoCompany/enhance-system-tree
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| |
| * | a71eb80 Grid now populates with data
|/ /
* |   e68ee8c Merge pull request #39 from demoCompany/create-kitchen-sink-tree
|\ \
| * | 67df38b Added kitchen sink tree panel
| * | e45e624 More simple updates
| * |   4100b5c Merge branch 'master' into create-kitchen-sink-tree
| |\ \
| | |/
| * | 5bc3fae .wakatime
| * | 0fb7ef9 README updated??
| * |   c67d24c Merge branch 'master' into create-kitchen-sink-tree
| |\ \
| * | | 376bd18 First draft of the system baseline tree
* | | |   6f59b6e Merge pull request #37 from demoCompany/Tree-Branch
|\ \ \ \
| * | | | b7bade7 Created Work Order Tree
| | |/ /
| |/| |
* | | | b488b16 Exlude SDK from indexing
* | | | 02a3f77 Updated .gitignore
* | | |   82e1bd6 Merge pull request #35 from demoCompany/mycmproapp-themes
|\ \ \ \
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
| * | | 916c1c5 removed steelgrey stub
| * | | e847962 changed build to steelgrey
| * | | 176b1de Testing Steel Grey switch
| * | | 8ef812e adding steelgray theme
| * | | 3c122f8 Created three themes
| |/ /
* | |   fe7abf2 Merge pull request #33 from demoCompany/Create-Grid
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| |
| * | 4676919 Add .history
| * | 5698194 Grid Create, Edit, Delete
* | | f0f55b0 Update README.md
* | | c5d6cce Added wakatime-project file
* | | 4a50b41 Simplified routing code
| |/
|/|
* |   a73c38f Merge pull request #28 from demoCompany/create-report
|\ \
:
```

Comment: Can you show the current branch structures of your repo by the commit `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Done. See update in OP. Thanks.

Comment: I meant can you show the histories at the point when you tried to finish the feature branch. I need to check your `feature` and `develop` branch's location. BTW: it's not necessary to pull/push `master` branch before finishing feature branch. Because start a feature branch will create a new branch from `develop` or `master`, and finish the feature will merge it into `develop` branch.